# Python BeautifulSoup parsing from specific table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here's a part of a script parsing HTML using BeautifulSoup. I am trying to get links from a page, which are later being used. 
Everything seems to be working fine, however I would like to get only some of those links and not all of them, by which I mean I am interested only in links placed in the first table on the page. I do realize I could just manually shorten the list, but that's not really gonna work for me.

Here's an url of the page: https://www.spotrac.com/nba/atlanta-hawks/cap/

Is there any way this can be done?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

req = Request("https://www.spotrac.com/nba/atlanta-hawks/cap/")
html_page = urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, features="html.parser")
links = []


for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    links.append(link.get('href'))
players=[]
i=0
while i<len(links):
    if "redirect/player" in links[i]:
        players.append(links[i])
    i+=1
print(players)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can narrow things down by first using `find` on the table containing the first set of names:

```
...
table = soup.find('tbody')

for link in table.find_all('a'):
...
```

By looking at the source code it appears the data you want is located in `tbody`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it seems to be the best way. I was using find_all instead of find and couldn't get it done.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust this code below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.spotrac.com/nba/atlanta-hawks/cap/'

headers = {'Host': 'www.spotrac.com',
           'Referer': 'https://www.spotrac.com/nba/atlanta-hawks/cap/',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}

pageTree = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageTree.content, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('tbody')
links = table.find_all('a')

for item in links:
    print(str(item.text), str(item['href']))
```

Result:

```
Kent Bazemore https://www.spotrac.com/redirect/player/11079/
Miles Plumlee https://www.spotrac.com/redirect/player/10851/
Dewayne Dedmon https://www.spotrac.com/redirect/player/13536/
Trae Young https://www.spotrac.com/redirect/player/26971/
Alex Len https://www.spotrac.com/redirect/player/13318/
Taurean Prince https://www.spotrac.com/redirect/player/20217/
Justin Anderson https://www.spotrac.com/redirect/player/17849/
John Collins https://www.spotrac.com/redirect/player/23614/
Kevin Huerter https://www.spotrac.com/redirect/player/26985/
DeAndre' Bembry https://www.spotrac.com/redirect/player/20226/
Omari Spellman https://www.spotrac.com/redirect/player/26996/
Vince Carter https://www.spotrac.com/redirect/player/2590/
Tyler Dorsey https://www.spotrac.com/redirect/player/23642/
Jaylen Adams https://www.spotrac.com/redirect/player/27343/
Jordan Sibert https://www.spotrac.com/redirect/player/18240/
```

If this is what you need, please mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was very helpful and works great for me, but I found l'L'l's solution much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a `first-child` css selector to restrict to first table; you can use a `descendant combinator` to then select the `href` attributes within the table (your links).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
url = 'https://www.spotrac.com/nba/atlanta-hawks/cap/'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('table:first-child [href]')]
print(links)
```

Comment: This, I believe, is actually more efficient as uses css selectors.